# Regex re negative lookahead doesn't exclude multiple characters successfully

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

There are 5 examples as below, and I am trying to find 3,4,5 while excluding 1,2.

1. ABC-abc
2. abc-ABC
3. ABC-ABC
4. ABC
5. vABC-ABC-ABCv

The current expression I use is:

```
(?!(\w*[A-Z]{2,}-[a-z]+\w*|\w*[a-z]+-[A-Z]{2,}\w*))(\w*-?[A-Z]{2,}-?\w*)
```

- I utilize (\w*-?[A-Z]{2,}-?\w*) to get all possibility of all examples first.
- I then use (?!...|...) to put two exclusion conditions.
- The first exclusion condition is \w*[A-Z]{2,}-[a-z]+\w* and the second is \w*[a-z]+-[A-Z]{2,}\w*.
- This expression works to exclude 1.ABC-abc but not abc-ABC.

I searched a lot and found some people say this way is not something regex is "good" at. Is there any solution or improvement I can do to get rid of abc-ABC.

Appreciate any help or opinion.

Comment: What is the *rule* you wish to enforce? For example, do you wish to match one or more hyphen-separated strings of three capital letters, optionally preceded and/or followed by a lower-case letter? Or perhaps your wish to match one or more hyphen-separated strings of *one or more* capital letters...". There are many possibilities. As here, you can rarely state a question unambiguously in terms of examples.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thanks for your clarification. The case I want to exclude is one hyphen-separated string comprised of at least one lowercase ahead or behind the hyphen, and the other side of the hyphen is uppercase (like from the example I give C-a or c-A). Appreciate your help!

Comment: When asked for clarification you should respond by editing your question, not elaborating in comments. Questions are meant to be self-contained, in part because not all readers read all comments, and if some comments are deleted others may no longer carry their original meaning. You should always begin questions with a statement of what you wish to achieve, before giving any examples.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand strings are to be rejected if they contain a hyphen that is preceded by a lower-case letter and followed by an upper-case letter, or vice-versa; else they are to be accepted. If so, the following regular expression could be used.

```
^(?!.*(?:[a-z]-[A-Z]|[A-Z]-[a-z]))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/icFNIM/2/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^                # match beginning of line
(?!              # begin a negative lookahead
  .*             # match 0+ characters
  (?:            # begin a non-capture group
    [a-z]-[A-Z]  # match a lc letter, '-', uc letter
    |            # or
    [A-Z]-[a-z]  # match an uc letter, '-', lc letter
  )              # end non-capture group
)                # end negative lookahead
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I just tried, but I found when the string has space in the front (eg. ' ABC-abc'), it doesn't work as expected. Can you please help to check again? Also, you mentioned that strings are to be rejected if they contain a hyphen that is preceded by a lower-case letter and followed by an upper-case letter, or vice-versa. However, when the uppercase is followed by hyphen and then lowercase, my code isn't rejected (only 'lowercase hyphen uppercase' is rejected). Do you know the reason? Thank you!

Comment: I don't follow. At the link both `ABC-abc` and `abc-ABC` (the first two examples) are rejected, and adding a space to the beginning of those strings makes no difference. If you wish to match the entire string of those strings that are valid add `.*` to the end of the regex, but what I have is sufficient to show whether a string is valid.

Comment: In case you hadn't noticed, you can make the changes I mentioned yourself at the link I gave.